# Resolution "scaled down", need to move mouse to edges to navigate the desktop

Tags: windows-7, intel-atom, intel-graphics, windows-embedded-7

I have installed Windows 7 Embedded Standard on a machine running an Intel E6xx. When in Windows the desktop is severely cut off, only displaying approx 600x400, even though I have set the resolution to 800x600 in the Intel Embedded Media and Graphics Driver. I have tried several different resolutions, but the resolution of the view remains the same, I only get a bigger desktop that I need to navigate around by moving my mouse to the edges of the viewable area ("scrolling" the desktop).

If I enter windows in safe mode I get the full 800x600 without any "scrolling".

Anybody familiar with this, and know how to fix it?

Comment: Is your screen capable of actually displaying the chosen higher resolution?